# Laravel Blade @foreach directive Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am facing the problem undefined index when trying to loop laravel pagination items. here is my code.

**Controller**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $term = request('q', '');

        $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$term%")->paginate(12);

        $products->appends(['q' => $term]);

        $data['products'] = $products;

        // dd( $products );

        return view('products.search', $data);
    }
}
```

**products/search.blade.php**

```
@foreach( $products as $prod )

<div class="post">

    <a href="{{ route('product.show', ['name' => $prod->id]) }}">

        <p class="post-title">{{ $prod->name }}</p>

    </a>

</div>

@foreach
```

**There is error**

[image]

Comment: do `var_dump($matches); die;`  to check if regular expression returns proper matches array

Comment: `$data['products'] = $products;` this isn't code igniter, don't do this

Comment: what should i do instead? $data['products'] = $products; i have tried something like this `$data['products'] = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$term%")->paginate(12)->appends(['q' => $term]);` but not working

Comment: where should i do this? `var_dump($matches); die;` where is `$matches`? i have tried `var_dump($matches); die;` in first line within loop but still same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you have an empty `@foreach` at the end, You close a foreach loop in blade using `@endforeach`

```
@foreach( $products as $prod )

<div class="post">

    <a href="{{ route('product.show', ['name' => $prod->id]) }}">

        <p class="post-title">{{ $prod->name }}</p>

    </a>

</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: ahmed i found that my blunder but any way thanks for your response.